# Getting HTML by URL

Tags: java, string, url, null, stringbuilder

I was trying to get some HTML by URL and put it into String. This is my effort:

```
public class 

    Bank {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            URL hh = new URL("https://m.hh.ru/");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(hh.openStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                inputLine.concat(inputLine);//returns null. WTF?
                System.out.println(inputLine);

            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        }
```

As I said I want to put it to `inputLine`, but it returns `NULL`.
What's wrong?

Comment: In Java `Strings` are **immutable**. Use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: There are several problems in this method. Better think it through again. One tip: the last call to `in.readLine` will set `inputLine` to `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for string concatenation. The loop should look like this:

```
String inputLine;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(inputLine).append("\n");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```